# WCF - netTcpBinding with clientCredentialType="Windows" - Across Domains

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-security, nettcpbinding

I am using netTcpBinding to try and access a WCF service.

- The ASP.NET web application that is attempting to access the service is hosted on a webserver in a DMZ network.
- The service is hosted on another server in another domain

I am attempting to connect via clientCredentialType windows.

But when the web application attempts to hit the service I am getting an authentication error. Is it possible to use clientCredentialType="Windows" to access a machine hosting a service on another domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible because if there is no trust between domains so the machine hosting the service cannot validate credentials of the account running the client on another machine.

Comment: So the only thing I have to do is make a trust between the 2 Active Directory domains?